# Creating a generic List <T> in F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to create a standard .NET `List<T>` in F# like this:

```
module Csv

open System;

type Sheet () =
  let rows = new List<Object>()
```

but I get the following error:

> *No constructors are available for the type `List<Object>`*
>   *`C:\…\Csv.fs`: 6*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As a simpler alternative to what others suggest, you can use the type named `ResizeArray<T>`. This is a type alias for `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` defined in the F# core libraries:

```
type Sheet () = 
  let rows = new ResizeArray<Object>()
```

In the compiled code, `ResizeArray<T>` will be compiled down to `System.Collections.Generic. List<T>`, so if you use your library from C#, there will not be any difference.

You do not have to open `System.Collections.Generic`, which would hide the definition of the F# `List<T>` type (though this is not a big problem), and I think that `ResizeArray` is a more appropriate name for the data structure anyway.

Answer (score 11):

You need to open `System.Collections.Generic`, too - the `List<_>` type you're referencing is F#'s immutable list type (from the `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections` namespace, which is opened by default), which doesn't expose public constructors.

Answer (score 9):

The [`List<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is defined in the [`System.Collections.Generic` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.generic.aspx), so you need to add:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
```