# .NET list of F# functions

Tags: .net, list, function, f#

I am trying to create a .NET list of F# functions, but it keeps telling me that it expects a something something, but has a 'a instead. I'm not sure, but I'm guessing it's because I can't create a .NET list of F# functions. Is this true?

For example, when I try:

```
let listOfFunctions = new List<int -> unit>()
```

The compiler complains accordingly:

`No constructors are available for the type 'List<(int -> unit)>'`

EDIT

After much thought, I realized, I forgot to open System.Collections.Generic, which caused the issue. I didn't notice the issue because the compiler thought it was an F# list, which doesn't have a constructor like .NET Lists do. However, it's confusing because the type signatures look the same. Consider the following code:

```
let FSharpList : List<int> = [1;2;3]
let DotNetList : List<int> = new List<int>()
```

If you don't use open System.Collections.Generic, the compiler assumes List to be an F# list, and the second line will obviously fail. But if you include it, then the compiler will assume List is a .NET list, and the first line will complain that [1;2;3] is supposed to have type `List<int>` but instead has type `'a list` (aka it's expecting a .NET list).

So actually, it had nothing to do with a list of functions at all. In fact, the following code:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let myList = new List<int -> unit>()
```

works just fine.

Comment: Can you post the code you're trying to use?

Comment: I think I get what the problem is, but as has been said, you should post the code you're trying to use.

Comment: @Guy Coder, I don't think this is a duplicate. The question you posted is asking about an F# list of F# functions. I'm trying to create a mutable .NET list of f# functions that I can add to using List.Add(element). They are totally different kinds of lists.

Comment: A few things small things: To help avoid exactly this confusion between the types, F# aliases `System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>` to `ResizeArray<'T>`. Also, it is often not necessary to explicitly state generic type parameters in F#. If you just write `ResizeArray<_>`, the compiler will try to figure out the type from how you use it. And thirdly, you don't *need* `new` in F# (the compiler will suggest using it for types implementing `IDisposable`, though).

Comment: I think that now this has been clarified it is probably just a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010316/creating-a-generic-list-t-in-f