# Passing a F# struct to C#

Tags: f#

I have the following error:

```
Library.fs(86, 40): [FS0193] Type constraint mismatch. The type 'struct (DateTime * Intervals * float * float) option list' is not compatible with type    'Collections.Generic.List<struct (DateTime * Intervals * float * float)>'
```

The issue is that the F# generates a struct option list and the C# is expecting an IEnumerable with the same types instead.

How can that be converted?

Edit:
here is the full error message:

> Library.fs(80, 40): [FS0001] The type 'struct (DateTime * Intervals * float * float) option list' is not compatible with the type 'Collections.Generic.List'
>     Library.fs(80, 40): [FS0193] Type constraint mismatch. The type 'struct (DateTime * Intervals * float * float) option list' is not compatible with type    'Collections.Generic.List'
>     Library.fs(81, 16): [FS0001] The type ''a option' does not match the type 'unit'

If I fill the structure with fields I know are not optional, I get the same error:

> struct (DateTime.MinValue, Intervals.Tick, 0.0, 0.0)

Screenshot added:

[image]

Edit:

I added the ToList() conversion, but it didn't help:

[image]

Comment: On F# side your list contains _optional_ values - i.e. some of them may be missing. What should happen with missing values?

Comment: none of the types should be optional in the F# code, they're a date, a C# enum and two floats.

Comment: Your type is `blah option list` - that means a list of `blah option` values.

Comment: I just hardcoded some parameters and the option has disappeared; so I have to track where it comes from. Now even without the option, I need to find how to convert

Comment: Now looks like you need to cast your item to List like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010316/creating-a-generic-list-t-in-f

Comment: You don't need to convert. F# `list` does implement `IEnumerable`

Comment: Oh, wait. The error text says "expecting `List<T>`", but your description say that you need to pass `IEnumerable`. So which is it?

Comment: Either, since List is part of IEnumerable; I need something I can iterate through on the C# side.

Comment: @Bohdan: I checked that link and it seems to work for simple types, but when I pass the struct as a type for the list, it won't compile

Comment: List is not "part of" IEnumerable. List implements IEnumerable, which means every List is an IEnumerable. But it is not true that every IEnumerable is a List. In fact, if you try to call your C# methods like `f( (IEnumerable<...>) null )`, the compiler will complain, because your method expects a `List`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that the wrong way; what I meant is that any collection I can iterate over is fine :)

Answer (score 3):

To create `List<T>` out of any other enumerable (including F# `list`) use the [`.ToList` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8) from `System.Linq.Enumerable`:

```
open System.Linq
...

db.AddQuotesList(Candle.Intervals.Tick, output.ToList())
```

Another way is to use one of `List`'s own constructors, which takes an enumerable as argument:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
...

db.AddQuotesList(Candle.Intervals.Tick, List(output))
```

Keep in mind, however, that doing this means memory allocation: `List` is not "lazy" like `IEnumerable` is, it will allocate a block of memory for all items when you construct it.

Comment: So, maybe the problem is how I generate the list to start with; I'm computing stock market candles and I have the following: let candles = times |> List.map(MakeOneCandle db interval) but this generates an option list; and the ToList() is not available then (I don't know if I mentioned earlier, but this is F# day 2 :))

Comment: `.ToList` is not available because you haven't opened `System.Linq`. It has nothing to do with `option`

Comment: `ResizeArray(output)` uses the F#-specific type abbreviation, if you'd like to have fewer overloads of "list" in the solution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.resizearray%5B't%5D-type-abbreviation-%5Bfsharp%5D

Comment: Small function for your library perhaps? ``let toResizeArray l = (ResizeArray (List.length l), l) ||> List.fold (fun a x -> a.Add x; a)``

Comment: @dumetrulo: that doesn't work in this case:   Library.fs(87, 53): [FS0001] The type ''a list -> ResizeArray<'a>' is not compatible with the type 'Collections.Generic.List<struct (DateTime * Candle.Intervals * float * float)>'

Comment: I edited the question with the call to ToList() to show the error.

Comment: @Thomas: How were you trying to use it? I was thinking along the lines of ``db.AddQuotesList(Candle.Intervals.Tick, output |> toResizeArray)``.

Comment: I can try that!